# Value sql is not a member of StringContext

Tags: scala, slick

Why, having the following code Scala returns `value sql is not a member of StringContext`?

I'm using Slick with Play Framework.

```
val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val query = sql"""select ID from TEACHER""".as[String] 
val people = db.withSession{ implicit session =>
Ok(query.list)
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I don't know about slick, but I have faced the same problem with anorm. I import the Interpolation with `import anorm.SqlStringInterpolation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the import `import driver.api._` from the library com.typesafe.play:play-slick_2.11:2.0.0. This should work:

```scala
import driver.api._

val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val query = sql"""select ID from TEACHER""".as[String] 
val people = db.withSession{ implicit session =>
Ok(query.list)
```

Comment: I am not using play, its a batch process. How can i resolve it overthere?

Comment: In this case, you could use the import `import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._` from the library `com.typesafe.slick:slick_2.11:3.1.1`. You can look at the documentation [there](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment above by "code4j" (but worthy of a separate answer), I use the following:

```
import anorm.SqlStringInterpolation
```

Note: this works with Anorm, independent of Slick.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
import Q.interpolation

val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val query = sql"""select ID from TEACHER""".as[String] 
val people = db.withSession{ implicit session =>
Ok(query.list)
```

Comment: what dependency do I need for it?